# how to add installed gdb to system path on linux

Tags: linux, ubuntu, gdb

At first，when I type 'gdb' anywhere that works.

```
(gdb)
```

But I need to work gdb with python2,then i remove current gdb and `make & make install` again,with python2 compiled.
Now, I can only run gdb at installed path but not anywhere.

If not on installed path,such warning is showed.

```
root@ubuntu:/home/yeah# gdb
bash: /usr/bin/gdb: No such file or directory
```

It seems i could assign the newly installed gdb path to certain system files,then i can use gdb anywhere.

But i dont know how to do this.

Any assistance is appreciated.

Comment: You have replaced the original gdb, but you did not remove the symbolic link in /usr/bin

Answer (score 0):

Reconfigure your user profile which is located in $HOME/.profile like PATH=$PATH:/usr/bin